# ">" In C function argument definition

Tags: c

I'm reading documentation for CFITSIO (C library for working with FITS images and other astronomical image data) when I come across an odd function definition.

```
int fits_movrel_hdu / ffmrhd
  (fitsfile *fptr, int nmove, > int *hdutype, int *status)
```

My question is what is the function of the ">" symbol in the third argument, int *hdutype.  I see it occurs in many other functions in this library, but I have never come across it in any other API or C Code that I can recall.

You can see more examples of this being used at [Hawaii's Telescope Software Page](http://software.cfht.hawaii.edu/cfitsio/node44.html)

Comment: It is interesting to note that ">" is pretty near "," on the keyboard; it might just be a typo in dead code. You said you found this in *documentation*; are you sure it is in code somewhere? Are you sure that the specific line of code actually *compiles*? That is, it isn't inside some preprocessor conditional that is disabled?

Comment: Are you sure that this code isn't pre-processed in any way? Are you sure it's built?

Comment: @Ira Yes the library compiles and this symbol shows up many times in various functions.  @yan It's possible it's preprocessed but that's why I'm asking the questions because I don't know what it does.

Comment: @NuclearGhost: You didn't really answer the question as to whether that *line* was compiled or just skipped.  And the compiler you are using is...?

Comment: There's an "Up" link in that Hawaii page ... :O

Comment: Based on the "Up" link in the Hawaii documentation, I'd guess that the ">" only exists in the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quote from [Advanced Interface Routines](http://software.cfht.hawaii.edu/cfitsio/node42.html) (the emphasis is mine) *(click "Up" in the page you linked to)*

> 1. Each routine has 2 names: a long descriptive name and a short concise name. Both names are listed on the first line of the following descriptions, separated by a slash (/) character.
> 2. A right arrow symbol (>) is used to **separate the input parameters from the output parameters** in the definition of each routine. This symbol is not actually part of the C calling sequence. Note that the status parameter is both an input and an output parameter.

Comment: Oh so by passing a pointer I check the value it's set to after the function returns and this is the correct value of the function.  The returned value must be used for error checking. That makes sense I just had not run across this before.

Comment: And the file in question... is it actually C code or something preprocessed?

Comment: Congratulations, you've been awarded the 'RTFM' badge.